# JSdom получить массив из ссылок

Tags: node.js, синтаксический-анализ, javascript

Помогите получить массив названий марок авто при парсинге страницы.
Код приведу чуть нижу.
На странице, марки автомобилей идут с подкатегориями, т.е. ссылки внутри класса .group и подкатегории внутри класса .subgroup

На данный момент собираю ссылки только из класса .group, но вот как быть с .subgroup, разобраться так и не смог =(

```
jsdom.env({
    url: URL,
    src: [jquery],
    done: function (err, window) {
        if(err) callback(err);

        var $ = window.$;

        $(".block.content td .group:not(:first) a").each(function () {
        models["name"] = $(this).text();

        console.log(models); // Получаю на выходе
            /*
            [ name: 'Defender' ]
            [ name: 'Discovery' ]
            [ name: 'Freelander' ]
            [ name: 'Range Rover' ]
            [ name: 'Range Rover Evoque' ]
            */

            /* Нужно к Range Rover прилепить массив его подкатегорий Range Rover и Range Rover Sport*/

        });
    }
});
```

Сам код страницы ниже:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="33%">
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="group">
                            <td>
                                <a href="link" style="font-weight:bold"></a>
                                <a href="link">Все</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="group">
                            <td>
                                <a href="link">Defender</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="group">
                            <td>
                                <a href="link">Discovery</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" width="33%">
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="group">
                            <td>
                                <a href="link">Freelander</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr class="group">
                        <td>
                            <a href="link" style="font-weight:bold">Range Rover</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="subgroup">
                        <td> 
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="link">Range Rover</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="subgroup">
                        <td> 
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="link">Range Rover Sport</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" width="33%">
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="group">
                            <td>
                                <a href="link">Range Rover Evoque</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, а то ручками вводить все замучаюсь =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас спасет [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$(".block.content td .group:not(:first) a").each(function () {
    model={
        name: $(this).text(),
        subnames: $(this).parents('tr').first().nextUntil('.group','.subgroup').find('a').map(function(i,e){
          return $(e).text();
        }).get()
    };
        console.log(model);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PUdzM/

Comment: спасибо! выручили

Comment: Не подскажите как сделать чуток по другому.
Чтобы создавался новый массив. Сейчас получаю массив из .subgroup моделей в виде:

 { models: 
    { name: 'Range Rover',
   class: [ 'Range Rover', 'Range Rover Sport' ] } }
 { models: { name: 'Range Rover Evoque', class: [] } }

А нужно .subgroup сделать новым массивом и в класс поместить марку к которой он принадлежит, т.е. Range Rover
Вот так:

 { models: { name: 'Range Rover', class: 'Range Rover' } }
 { models: { name: 'Range Rover Sport', class: 'Range Rover' } }
 { models: { name: 'Range Rover Evoque', class: '' } }

Comment: так что-ли ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PUdzM/3/ но я бы на вашем месте все таки бы сделал

    [class: "Range Rover", models: []]

или вообще 

    {'Range Rover': ['Range Rover', 'Range Rover Sport']}

Comment: Ага, так, спасибо еще раз )

Я вобще не могу определиться если честно как лучше сделать.
Сейчас пробую варианты которые вы помогли реализовать, до этого пробовал другие варианты которые у самого получилось написать, и все равно не определенность, но последний вариант вроде то что нужно =)
Спасибо!